# Cannot include <ncurses.h> header using nixos derivation

Tags: c++, ncurses, nixos

I have this simple c++ code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

which I try to build with this `shell.nix` file

```
{stdenv , ncurses}:
with import <nixpkgs> {}; {
     testEnv = stdenv.mkDerivation {
       name = "helloTest";
       buildInputs = [stdenv ncurses];
     };
}
```

Running the command:

```
g++ main.cpp -lncurses -o main
```

I get the error output:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
#include <ncurses.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

although I do have `ncurses` installed:

```
$ locate ncurses.h
/nix/store/ffjl7aw7f0gjwv4gb4mgb0w49v5dhrkg-ncurses-6.0-20171125-dev/include/ncurses.h
```

For the moment I was using a dedicated `docker` container for c++ builds. But I would like to avoid that, really awkward, and use the nix system properly.

Any idea what I'm obviously missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it works fine after fixing the `shell.nix` file and entering the commands below. The problem with `shell.nix` was that it was unnecessarily wrapped in a lambda. Its parameters were shadowed by the `with;` expression anyway, so you can just remove the outer lambda.

```
$ cat shell.nix
with import <nixpkgs> {};
{
     testEnv = stdenv.mkDerivation {
       name = "helloTest";
       buildInputs = [stdenv ncurses];
     };
}
$ nix-shell

[nix-shell:~/tmp/so-54524324]$ g++ main.cpp -lncurses -o main

[nix-shell:~/tmp/so-54524324]$ ./main 

[nix-shell:~/tmp/so-54524324]$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the advise of a previous answer I can compile hapilly with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
ncursesInclude="/nix/store/ffjl7aw7f0gjwv4gb4mgb0w49v5dhrkg-ncurses-6.0-20171125-dev/include/"
ncursesLib="/nix/store/54cwjh1lsmjpk2cbs43gw89w4zhk3ybb-ncurses-6.0-20171125/lib/"
g++ main.cpp -I$ncursesInclude -L$ncursesLib -lncurses -o main
```

But I feel terribly awkward the need to have the concrete path to the nix store.

I would gladly know the nix way of doing that.